# extrair dados na lista

Tags: java

Fiz umas tentativas, mais ainda estou apanhando segue o que acrescentei no código.

Como posso fazer essa limitação dentro do código que resulte no fechamento abaixo? Me faltou lógica de como implementar lendo dados a partir de arquivo texto.

Aqui se tem 4 se 4 (10 dezenas).

- Exemplo1:

se forem sorteadas: 1,3,5,6,8,9 entre as 10 eu tenho 
uma quadra ou varias.

- Exemplo2:

vamos supor outro sorteio que errei duas dezenas 12 e 19 tipo: 1,3,5,6,12,19
neste caso só acertei 4 entre as 10, se procurar essas 4 dezenas no fechamento abaixo, eu tenho pelo menos esse conjunto ou seja uma quadra.

```
********************************************
resultado a ser alcançado
********************************************

total dezenas: 10
conjunto 6
garantia 4
para acerto 4

01 02 03 04 05 06,
01 02 03 05 07 09,
01 02 03 06 07 08,
01 02 03 06 09 10,
01 02 04 06 07 10,
01 02 04 07 08 09,
01 02 05 07 08 10,
01 03 04 05 07 10,
01 03 04 05 08 09,
01 03 05 06 08 10,
01 04 06 08 09 10,
01 05 06 07 09 10,
02 03 04 06 08 09,
02 03 04 07 09 10,
02 03 05 08 09 10,
02 04 05 06 07 09,
02 04 05 06 08 10,
03 04 06 07 08 10,
03 05 06 07 08 09,
04 05 07 08 09 10,
```

para facilitar estou postando

lista.txt

```
01  02  03  04  05  06,
01  02  03  04  05  07,
01  02  03  04  05  08,
01  02  03  04  05  09,
01  02  03  04  05  10,
01  02  03  04  06  07,
01  02  03  04  06  08,
01  02  03  04  06  09,
01  02  03  04  06  10,
01  02  03  04  07  08,
01  02  03  04  07  09,
01  02  03  04  07  10,
01  02  03  04  08  09,
01  02  03  04  08  10,
01  02  03  04  09  10,
01  02  03  05  06  07,
01  02  03  05  06  08,
01  02  03  05  06  09,
01  02  03  05  06  10,
01  02  03  05  07  08,
01  02  03  05  07  09,
01  02  03  05  07  10,
01  02  03  05  08  09,
01  02  03  05  08  10,
01  02  03  05  09  10,
01  02  03  06  07  08,
01  02  03  06  07  09,
01  02  03  06  07  10,
01  02  03  06  08  09,
01  02  03  06  08  10,
01  02  03  06  09  10,
01  02  03  07  08  09,
01  02  03  07  08  10,
01  02  03  07  09  10,
01  02  03  08  09  10,
01  02  04  05  06  07,
01  02  04  05  06  08,
01  02  04  05  06  09,
01  02  04  05  06  10,
01  02  04  05  07  08,
01  02  04  05  07  09,
01  02  04  05  07  10,
01  02  04  05  08  09,
01  02  04  05  08  10,
01  02  04  05  09  10,
01  02  04  06  07  08,
01  02  04  06  07  09,
01  02  04  06  07  10,
01  02  04  06  08  09,
01  02  04  06  08  10,
01  02  04  06  09  10,
01  02  04  07  08  09,
01  02  04  07  08  10,
01  02  04  07  09  10,
01  02  04  08  09  10,
01  02  05  06  07  08,
01  02  05  06  07  09,
01  02  05  06  07  10,
01  02  05  06  08  09,
01  02  05  06  08  10,
01  02  05  06  09  10,
01  02  05  07  08  09,
01  02  05  07  08  10,
01  02  05  07  09  10,
01  02  05  08  09  10,
01  02  06  07  08  09,
01  02  06  07  08  10,
01  02  06  07  09  10,
01  02  06  08  09  10,
01  02  07  08  09  10,
01  03  04  05  06  07,
01  03  04  05  06  08,
01  03  04  05  06  09,
01  03  04  05  06  10,
01  03  04  05  07  08,
01  03  04  05  07  09,
01  03  04  05  07  10,
01  03  04  05  08  09,
01  03  04  05  08  10,
01  03  04  05  09  10,
01  03  04  06  07  08,
01  03  04  06  07  09,
01  03  04  06  07  10,
01  03  04  06  08  09,
01  03  04  06  08  10,
01  03  04  06  09  10,
01  03  04  07  08  09,
01  03  04  07  08  10,
01  03  04  07  09  10,
01  03  04  08  09  10,
01  03  05  06  07  08,
01  03  05  06  07  09,
01  03  05  06  07  10,
01  03  05  06  08  09,
01  03  05  06  08  10,
01  03  05  06  09  10,
01  03  05  07  08  09,
01  03  05  07  08  10,
01  03  05  07  09  10,
01  03  05  08  09  10,
01  03  06  07  08  09,
01  03  06  07  08  10,
01  03  06  07  09  10,
01  03  06  08  09  10,
01  03  07  08  09  10,
01  04  05  06  07  08,
01  04  05  06  07  09,
01  04  05  06  07  10,
01  04  05  06  08  09,
01  04  05  06  08  10,
01  04  05  06  09  10,
01  04  05  07  08  09,
01  04  05  07  08  10,
01  04  05  07  09  10,
01  04  05  08  09  10,
01  04  06  07  08  09,
01  04  06  07  08  10,
01  04  06  07  09  10,
01  04  06  08  09  10,
01  04  07  08  09  10,
01  05  06  07  08  09,
01  05  06  07  08  10,
01  05  06  07  09  10,
01  05  06  08  09  10,
01  05  07  08  09  10,
01  06  07  08  09  10,
02  03  04  05  06  07,
02  03  04  05  06  08,
02  03  04  05  06  09,
02  03  04  05  06  10,
02  03  04  05  07  08,
02  03  04  05  07  09,
02  03  04  05  07  10,
02  03  04  05  08  09,
02  03  04  05  08  10,
02  03  04  05  09  10,
02  03  04  06  07  08,
02  03  04  06  07  09,
02  03  04  06  07  10,
02  03  04  06  08  09,
02  03  04  06  08  10,
02  03  04  06  09  10,
02  03  04  07  08  09,
02  03  04  07  08  10,
02  03  04  07  09  10,
02  03  04  08  09  10,
02  03  05  06  07  08,
02  03  05  06  07  09,
02  03  05  06  07  10,
02  03  05  06  08  09,
02  03  05  06  08  10,
02  03  05  06  09  10,
02  03  05  07  08  09,
02  03  05  07  08  10,
02  03  05  07  09  10,
02  03  05  08  09  10,
02  03  06  07  08  09,
02  03  06  07  08  10,
02  03  06  07  09  10,
02  03  06  08  09  10,
02  03  07  08  09  10,
02  04  05  06  07  08,
02  04  05  06  07  09,
02  04  05  06  07  10,
02  04  05  06  08  09,
02  04  05  06  08  10,
02  04  05  06  09  10,
02  04  05  07  08  09,
02  04  05  07  08  10,
02  04  05  07  09  10,
02  04  05  08  09  10,
02  04  06  07  08  09,
02  04  06  07  08  10,
02  04  06  07  09  10,
02  04  06  08  09  10,
02  04  07  08  09  10,
02  05  06  07  08  09,
02  05  06  07  08  10,
02  05  06  07  09  10,
02  05  06  08  09  10,
02  05  07  08  09  10,
02  06  07  08  09  10,
03  04  05  06  07  08,
03  04  05  06  07  09,
03  04  05  06  07  10,
03  04  05  06  08  09,
03  04  05  06  08  10,
03  04  05  06  09  10,
03  04  05  07  08  09,
03  04  05  07  08  10,
03  04  05  07  09  10,
03  04  05  08  09  10,
03  04  06  07  08  09,
03  04  06  07  08  10,
03  04  06  07  09  10,
03  04  06  08  09  10,
03  04  07  08  09  10,
03  05  06  07  08  09,
03  05  06  07  08  10,
03  05  06  07  09  10,
03  05  06  08  09  10,
03  05  07  08  09  10,
03  06  07  08  09  10,
04  05  06  07  08  09,
04  05  06  07  08  10,
04  05  06  07  09  10,
04  05  06  08  09  10,
04  05  07  08  09  10,
04  06  07  08  09  10,
05  06  07  08  09  10,

***********************//*******************
```

codigo em java

```
package br.teste;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LerArquivoTxT {

    ArrayList<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String[]> novaLista = new ArrayList<>();

    public void LerArquivo(){

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Conteudo/listaIII.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String temp;

            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                lista.add(temp.split(";"));
                compararLista(lista);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo nao encontrado!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LerArquivoTxT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        lista.forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
    }

    // METODO PARA COMPARA OS CONJUNTOS
    public void compararLista(ArrayList<String[]> lista) {        

        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {            
            for(int j = i + 1; j < lista.size(); j++) {
                if(lista.get(i).equals(lista.get(j))){
                    lista.remove(j);
                    j--;                    
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // SALVAR O ARQUIVO EM DISCO
    public void SalvarResumoDaLista(ArrayList<String[]> lista) throws IOException {
        try {

            FileOutputStream arquivo = new FileOutputStream("C:/Conteudo/RESUMO.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream gravador = new ObjectOutputStream(arquivo);
            gravador.writeObject(lista);
            gravador.close();
            arquivo.close();            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LerArquivoTxT lista = new LerArquivoTxT();
        lista.LerArquivo();

        ArrayList<String[]> lista2 = null;
        try {
            lista.SalvarResumoDaLista(lista2);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Conteudo salvo com sucesso!");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está a ler cada linha e fazendo `split(";")`, no entanto só vejo `,` nas várias linhas. Para além disse se cada `,` está no fim de cada linha então torna-se desnecessário pois a quebra de linha já irá servir de separação entre as várias linhas.

Comment: bom dia Isac se eu não usar o split ele vai considerar cada numero separando pela virgula assim, 0,1, 0,2, 0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6 ao no caso do numero 10 ele vai colocar as 1,0, se eu tirar o zero fica assim 1,2,3,4,5,1,0. se ultimo numero for 10.